# Scala.js Missing JS library/

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

I want to add jquery by `jsDependencies`.

I tried

```
libraryDependencies += "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.8.1"

jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.4" / "2.1.4/jquery.js"
```

resulted in:

```
Missing JS library: 2.1.3/jquery.js
```

and

```
jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.4" / "2.1.4/jquery.js"
```

resulted in:

```
  Possible paths found on the classpath:
  - scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/jquery.js
  - META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js
```

How can I add jquery to my dependencies?

**UPDATE 1:**
I created a workaround to remove scala/tools js libraries:

```
(scalaJSNativeLibraries in Compile) <<= (scalaJSNativeLibraries in Compile).map({ l =>
  println("scalaJSNativeLibraries: " + l.data.map(x => x.toURI).mkString("\n"))
  l.map(virtualFiles => virtualFiles.filter(vf => {
    val f=vf.toURI.toString
    val no = f.endsWith(".js") && f.contains("scala/tools")
    if(no){
      println(s"removing $f")
    }
    ! no
  }))
})
```

Result:

```
scalaJSNativeLibraries: virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/diagrams.js
virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/index.js
virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/jquery-ui.js
virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/jquery.js
virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/jquery.layout.js
virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/modernizr.custom.js
virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/raphael-min.js
virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/scheduler.js
virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/template.js
virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/tools.tooltip.js
virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.webjars/jquery/jars/jquery-2.1.3.jar:META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js
virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.webjars/jquery/jars/jquery-2.1.3.jar:META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.webjars/jquery/jars/jquery-2.1.3.jar:META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/2.1.3/webjars-requirejs.js
removing virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/diagrams.js
removing virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/index.js
removing virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/jquery-ui.js
removing virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/jquery.js
removing virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/jquery.layout.js
removing virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/modernizr.custom.js
removing virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/raphael-min.js
removing virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/scheduler.js
removing virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/template.js
removing virtualfile:/home/nyxos/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/tools.tooltip.js
```

**Update 2**

I think the problem is caused by the scala-lang dependency and scala.js `scalaJSNativeLibraries` including all js files. Scala-compiler contains the js files like `org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar:scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/jquery.js`.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % sv
```

**update 3*
In the `0.9.0` version it works:

```
libraryDependencies += "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.9.0"
jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.4" / "2.1.4/jquery.js"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a "feature" of scalajs-jquery 0.8.x that has caused more harm than good.

It is fixed in scalajs-jquery 0.9.0.:

```
libraryDependencies += "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.9.0"
jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.4" / "2.1.4/jquery.js"
```

Comment: That does not fix the problem.

Comment: It worked perfectly well for me here: https://github.com/scala-js/scalajs-tutorial/commit/0e7195dab6a4391761377c8df49f95cddc8f2b41 :-s

Comment: did you try with `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % sv ` ?

Comment: Yes, it works just as fine. Are you sure you have written `"2.1.4/jquery.js"` after the `/`? If you just say `"jquery.js"` you will have issues.